# Error saving Datatable records to DB

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to save data in my db (look the picture below)

[image]

but I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: 'insertCell' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLTableRowElement

```js
//ADDING NEW ITEM INTO THE ITEM TABLE
 $(document).on('submit', '#product_form', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  //btn_action="add_pricelvl"; //Set variable to call the add new item 
  var valdata = $(this).serialize(); //Array with field value 
  var tax = $('#item_tax').val(); //checkbox tax 
  var taxvalue = $('#item_taxvalue').val(); //inputbox tax
  var tabledets = it_det //Read the detail table
   .rows()
   .data();
  var arr1=[];
  var i=0;
  //Put the datatable rows in the array
  for (i=0; i<tabledets.length; i++){
   arr1[i]=tabledets.rows(i).data(); 
  }
       
  //call ajax function and send variable to php file.
  $.ajax({   
   url:'item_action.php',
            method:"POST",
            data:{
    //btn_action:btn_action, I can recovery this value in PHP file
    valdata:valdata,
    tax:tax,
    taxvalue:taxvalue,
    arr1:arr1
    },   
            success : function(data)
            {     
    $('#product_form')[0].reset();
                $('#productModal').modal('hide');
                $('#alert_action').fadeIn().html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
    $('#alert_action').fadeIn().html(result);
    $('#action').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#item_data').DataTable().ajax.reload();                
            },
   error : function () {
    $('<div>').html('Found an error!');
   }
  })
 });
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 table-responsive">
    <table id="item_pricelvl" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>            
          <th>Price Level</th>
          <th>Pricing Method</th>         
          <th>From Quantity</th>
          <th>To Quantity</th>         
          <th>Discount Amount</th>         
          <th>Unit Price</th>
          <th><input type="checkbox" class="checkall" /></th>            
        </tr>
      </thead>                 
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I copy the datatable contents in an array to save data in php file???? I gotta do in different way?

---

## Solved

```js
for (i=0; i<tabledets.length; i++){
  arr1[i]=tabledets.row(i).data(); 
}
```

Comment: It would be useful to have html code also.

Comment: I don't see `insertCell` anywhere in that code.

Comment: Exactly I don't have insertCell in my javascript code because insertCell is in jquery code, btw I copied the HTML code .

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. [`insertCell()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell) is a native Javascript function.  If you're using some third-party jQuery plugin or something, you should mention that.  Also, you have `var tabledets = it_det`, but I don't see `it_det` defined anywhere.

Comment: Show your item_action.php code as well.

Comment: I found the error! It wan into the foreach loop, tabledets.rows(i).data() is wrong, the exact code is: tabledets.row(i).data()

Comment: Voting to close as a typo